# Elasticsearch Snapshot / Repositories

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I understand that setting up a repo path in config yml file is possible:

```
path.repo: C:\repo
```

and that changing repository cannot be done dynamically.

What is then about Put snapshot repository API:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-register-repository.html

I try to set up a repo using this api using NEST wrapper:

```
await this.elasticClient.Snapshot.CreateRepositoryAsync(new CreateRepositoryRequest("repoName")).ConfigureAwait(false);

await this.elasticClient.Snapshot.CreateRepositoryAsync("repoName", x => x.FileSystem(f => f.Settings(backupLocation))).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

both fail. I really don't get how this is supposed to work.
How do I setup/change repos at runtime? Restarting ES is not a problem...

Comment: What is the error in your application and in the elasticsearch logs? I think you need to use forward slashes in the config, `c:/repo`. Have you restarted your cluster after you added the config in the `elasticsearch.yml`? Update your question with the errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
path.repo: C:\\repo
```

`path.repo` is an *allow list* of locations under which Elasticsearch is allowed to create repositories. Attempting to create a repository outside of a location specified in `path.repo` will fail.

Once `path.repo` is specified in elasticsearch.yml, it's possible to register an `fs` snapshot repository at the location with `.elasticClient.Snapshot.CreateRepositoryAsync(...)`.